# PhoneGap Build 3.1 Vibration notication won't work in android

Tags: android, cordova, build

I've been struggle for some times to make it work the vibration notification with PhoneGap build version 3.1.0

DeviceReady works, and I'm getting alert and beep notifications but not vibrate. The app resides in an external server and is dynamic based on PHP.

**NOTE:** I'm using the **cordova.android.js** from here http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/ **"cordova-3.1.0-src.zip"**. After unzipping, the file was residing under **"cordova-android.zip" -> test/assets/www/cordova.android.js**. I don't know if this is the right file, but I'm not getting errors whatsoever when I run the app.

When the app is built in PhoneGap (online) not standalone, I can see the plugin installed as follow:

**Installed PhoneGap Plugins**
org.apache.cordova.device  -  0.2.8
org.apache.cordova.dialogs -    0.2.6
org.apache.cordova.vibration - 0.3.7

**Here is my xml config file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id = "com.craving.craving"
        version = "1.1">
    <name>Two Minute Craving Dr.</name>
    <description>
        Web App by Support
    </description>
    <author href="http://sampe.com" email="support@support.com">
        Support Team
    </author>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.1.0" />
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification" />
     </feature>
     <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.vibration" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
    <preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="5000" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <icon src="images/icon-72.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" gap:role="default" />
    <gap:splash src="images/screen-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

**html /php code**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title><?=$metatitle;?></title>
<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=0.6667, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/js/cordova.android.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
   navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);
   navigator.notification.alert("Hello");
   navigator.notification.beep(1);   
  //alert();
}, false);
 </script>
</head>
<body>
code goes here
</body>
</html>
```

ANY VALID ANSWER OR HELP IS REALLY APPRECIATED!

Thank you all